# AngularJs open PDFs avoiding reader notification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows, internet-explorer

On windows 7, and ONLY on IE (Chrome & Firefox working like a charm), when I set an open call to a PDF file with Angularjs:

```
$windows.open(/path/to/file.pdf);
```

It happens to ask you if you want to open the file or download it, if you select open the file, it comes a further notification that ask you with which editor you want to open it, this even if default editor is set to Acrobat Reader.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid being asked for the reader and jump directly to Acrobat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure your default PDF viewer program on your OS once.

- Search a PDF file on your system
- Right click on it. Inside the context menu "open with" click on "choose default programm
- Inside your "open with" screen now select the your default programm and tick "Always use the selected proramm to open this kind of file".
- Press "ok"

#### > done